# Calculate nfl win and loss streak based on team and win/loss column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an Excel spreadsheet that calculates the winning/losing streak of an NFL dataset using the Team and Win/Loss columns, and I'd like to put this into a panda dataframe as part of my automation project (just a hobby). Here's a sample of the data in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'DB Date': {0: 20190905,
      1: 20190905,
      2: 20190915,
      3: 20190915,
      4: 20190922,
      5: 20190923},
     'Week': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3},
     'Team': {0: 'Bears',
      1: 'Packers',
      2: 'Bears',
      3: 'Packers',
      4: 'Packers',
      5: 'Bears'},
     'Opponent': {0: 'Packers',
      1: 'Bears',
      2: 'Broncos',
      3: 'Vikings',
      4: 'Broncos',
      5: 'Redskins'},
     'Home/Away': {0: 'home',
      1: 'away',
      2: 'away',
      3: 'home',
      4: 'home',
      5: 'away'},
     'Team Score': {0: 3, 1: 10, 2: 16, 3: 21, 4: 27, 5: 31},
     'Opp Score': {0: 10, 1: 3, 2: 14, 3: 16, 4: 16, 5: 15},
     'Win/Loss': {0: 'Loss', 1: 'Win', 2: 'Win', 3: 'Win', 4: 'Win', 5: 'Win'}})
```

I'm trying to add a new column that calculates the winning/losing streak to this dataframe. Here's what I have from my Excel file:

```
DB Date     Week    Team    Opponent    Team Score  Opp Score   Win/Loss
20190905    1       Bears   Packers        3           10       L1
20190905    1       Packers Bears          10          3        W1
20190915    2       Bears   Broncos        16          14       W1
20190915    2       Packers Vikings        21          16       W2
20190922    3       Packers Broncos        27          16       W3
20190923    3       Bears   Redskins       31          15       W2
20190926    4       Packers Eagles         27          34       L1
20190929    4       Bears   Vikings        16          6        W3
20191006    5       Packers Cowboys        34          24       W1
20191006    5       Bears   Raiders        21          24       L1
```

As a total beginner to Python, I have no clue how to create a function that will create this "Win Streak" column. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this!

Edit:

```
{'DB Date': {0: 20190905,
  1: 20190905,
  2: 20190915,
  3: 20190915,
  4: 20190922,
  5: 20190923,
  6: 20190926,
  7: 20190929,
  8: 20191006,
  9: 20191006,
  10: 20191014,
  11: 20191020,
  12: 20191020},
 'Week': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 2,
  4: 3,
  5: 3,
  6: 4,
  7: 4,
  8: 5,
  9: 5,
  10: 6,
  11: 7,
  12: 7},
 'Team': {0: 'Bears',
  1: 'Packers',
  2: 'Bears',
  3: 'Packers',
  4: 'Packers',
  5: 'Bears',
  6: 'Packers',
  7: 'Bears',
  8: 'Packers',
  9: 'Bears',
  10: 'Packers',
  11: 'Bears',
  12: 'Packers'},
 'Opponent': {0: 'Packers',
  1: 'Bears',
  2: 'Broncos',
  3: 'Vikings',
  4: 'Broncos',
  5: 'Redskins',
  6: 'Eagles',
  7: 'Vikings',
  8: 'Cowboys',
  9: 'Raiders',
  10: 'Lions',
  11: 'Saints',
  12: 'Raiders'},
 'Home/Away': {0: 'home',
  1: 'away',
  2: 'away',
  3: 'home',
  4: 'home',
  5: 'away',
  6: 'home',
  7: 'home',
  8: 'away',
  9: 'neutral',
  10: 'home',
  11: 'home',
  12: 'home'},
 'Team Score': {0: 3,
  1: 10,
  2: 16,
  3: 21,
  4: 27,
  5: 31,
  6: 27,
  7: 16,
  8: 34,
  9: 21,
  10: 23,
  11: 25,
  12: 42},
 'Opp Score': {0: 10,
  1: 3,
  2: 14,
  3: 16,
  4: 16,
  5: 15,
  6: 34,
  7: 6,
  8: 24,
  9: 24,
  10: 22,
  11: 36,
  12: 24},
 'Win/Loss': {0: 'Loss',
  1: 'Win',
  2: 'Win',
  3: 'Win',
  4: 'Win',
  5: 'Win',
  6: 'Loss',
  7: 'Win',
  8: 'Win',
  9: 'Loss',
  10: 'Win',
  11: 'Loss',
  12: 'Win'}}
```

Comment: How many rows do you expect in your input data frame approximately? I have posted an answer ...pls check and accept if it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

def make_streak(S1):
    ''' This function takes the values of Win/Loss column as input and returns a list of streak values
    eg: input list : ['Loss', 'Win', 'Win', 'Win', 'Loss', 'Loss']
    output list : ['L1', 'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'L1', 'L2'] '''
    S2 = []
    for i in range(len(S1)):
        if i==0:
            S2.append(S1[i][0]+'1');continue
        if S1[i] != S1[i-1]:
            S2.append(S1[i][0]+'1')
        if S1[i] == S1[i-1]:
            S2.append(S1[i][0]+str(int(S2[-1][-1])+1))
    return S2

def create_col(row):
    ''' This function takes every row of df as input, and returns the value for the new column:'Win/Loss Streak'(to be created)'''
    df_temp = df[(df['Team'] == row['Team'])] #Create a temporary dataframe with passed in row's team name
    df_temp['Streak'] = make_streak(df_temp['Win/Loss'].tolist())
    return (df_temp[ df_temp['row_num'] == row['row_num']]['Streak'].values[0]) #Return df_temp's last column value which matches passed in row's row number

df['row_num'] = np.arange(1,len(df)+1) #Creates a column 'row_num' to identify the rows uniquely
df['Win Streak'] = df.apply(create_col,axis=1) #Call create_col function and create 'Win Streak' column
df.drop(columns = 'row_num', inplace = True) #Drop the column 'row_num'
df
```

[image: Final Dataframe in Jupyter]

Comment: you're amazing! I was thinking how to solve this problem the whole night but couldn't come up with anything. this is a surprise waking up to find a solution available! thanks again!

Comment: Glad - it worked for you. Up-voted your question for a good challenge and clarity. Cheers!

Comment: Hi again, sorry for bothering you, but I just tried to apply this function to my whole dataset and noticed that the "Win Streak" column is not resetting itself. For example, instead of being L1, W1, W2, W3, and L1, it's L1, W1, W2, W3, and L2. is there a way to reset the streak whenever it changes from Win to Loss (or Loss to Win)?

Comment: Hi, please see the dictionary of the Dataframe in the edited post above. It does work fine if there's no prior history of Loss/Win, but if there is, it's acting as a continuation instead of a reset.

Comment: not at all, i'm very thankful to have your help. please see my edited excel table above.

Comment: the date is only there for the chronological order. it does not determine the streak. if the team score > opp score, it's a win. otherwise, it's a loss. for example, when the packers played the eagles, the team score < opp score so it's a loss. and because the previous streak was W3 (3 straight wins against Broncos, Vikings, and Bears), the streak is changed to L1.

Comment: My question was different: Bears lost to Packers (the first row), The streak is L1. When again they lost to Raiders (in the last row) why is it still L1 ? Should it not be L2 as they lost second time (Based on your logic provided earlier)

Comment: Hi, in Week 1, the bears lost so the streak is L1. then in the next 3 weeks (2,3, and 4), they were all wins. on week 5, they played and won so its a win. so the expectation on the "Win Loss Streak" column is: Week 1 = L1, Week 2 = W1, Week 3 = W2, Week 4 = W3, Week 5 = L1. any time the streak changes, it gets reset. i hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: I better learn bit more about Games than python. Had to literally google 'winning / loosing streak' meaning. Now I get what you mean when you say 'streak changes'. Please try the edited code in my answer on your complete data set and let me know if it works.

Comment: haha, it works perfectly. i wish i could trade my worthless sports knowledge for your python skills. :) thanks so much for the code and have a great day!